# Logstash service stops alone after few seconds

Tags: unix, service, logstash, elastic-stack, freebsd

I'm trying to configure for the first time `ElasticSearch - Kibana - Logstash` on my `FreeBSD` server.

I installed `Logstash` with pkg.

I wrote in **/etc/rc.conf** file:

```
logstash_enable="YES"
logstash_config="/usr/local/etc/logstash/*.conf"   
logstash_log="YES"
logstash_log_file="/var/log/logstash.log"
```

I set **jvm.options** in **/usr/local/logstash/conﬁg/jvm.options** like this:

```
# Xms represents the initial size of total heap space 
# Xmx represents the maximum size of total heap space
-Xms256m 
-Xmx1g
```

Than, when I execute:

```
service logstash start
```

I get:

```
root@toto:/var/log/elasticsearch # service logstash start
Starting logstash.
root@toto:/var/log/elasticsearch # service logstash status
logstash is running as pid 12769.
root@toto:/var/log/elasticsearch # service logstash status
logstash is running as pid 12769.
root@toto:/var/log/elasticsearch # service logstash status
logstash is running as pid 12769.
root@toto:/var/log/elasticsearch # service logstash status
logstash is running as pid 12769.
root@toto:/var/log/elasticsearch # service logstash status
logstash is running as pid 12769.
root@toto:/var/log/elasticsearch # service logstash status
logstash is not running.
```

Each command is executed 1 second after the previous one. I don't understand why I lost the `logstash.pid`.

According to my configuration in /etc/rc.conf, I don't have any logstash.log too.

Do you have any idea ?

**EDIT:**

According to @MarcoSantos's answer, this is what I get:

```
root          85439  0.0  0.0    6376   2032  -  SsJ  09:11     0:00.00 daemon: /usr/local/logstash/bin/logstash[92803] (daemon)
root           8461  0.0  0.0    6644   2396  4  S+J  09:11     0:00.00 grep -i logstash
```

It's ok because logstash is used as daemon. But 6 seconds after the start, I get:

```
root           8461  0.0  0.0    6644   2396  4  S+J  09:11     0:00.00 grep -i logstash
```

Why my daemon stop alone ?

Comment: When you start the logstash process with "service logstash start", check "ps aux | grep -i logstash", you will get how the logtash is being launched in the system (logtash with some additional arguments), copy that to your shell and start the process that way, It will probably start logtash in foreground and you will get some more output about why is crashing.

Comment: @MarcoSantos I edited my question with your answer.